# Add the dictionary instead of overwrite - defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a dictionary named "n" which will have a key value relation in it(Dict inside dict).

Here Key will be an tenant_id `(b77865b66fd544e0841aa7dbca8bdc97, 7b73b9644e8242b3a740afc4659d9829)`.

So Dict will be having a key value pair relation in such a way that it tenant_id and its related instance names in it.

Sample code:

```
    n = defaultdict(dict)

    r = q.all()

    # For getting the values of sql obj
    for m in r:

            g = m.__dict__

            g.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)

            tenant_id = g['tenant_id']

            n[tenant_id] = g

    n = json.dumps(n, default=json_util.default)
```

So now one tenant will be having more that one instances.

Here I am facing the issue with overwriting of values related to the key.

I need to add the dict here instead of overwriting it.

Here I have provided the same results to make sense.

Expected result:

```
{u'b77865b66fd544e0841aa7dbca8bdc97': {u'instance_name': u'instance_for_test'},{u'instance_name': u'new_instance'}, u'7b73b9644e8242b3a740afc4659d9829': {u'instance_name': u'demo'}}
```

Actual result:

```
{u'b77865b66fd544e0841aa7dbca8bdc97': {u'instance_name': u'new_instance'}, u'7b73b9644e8242b3a740afc4659d9829': {u'instance_name': u'demo'}}
```

Someone let me know the solution for the issue.

Note:

I have tried append and extend etc., But as it is Dict it seems not to be working.

Comment: The values of your dictionary should be lists - lists of dictionaries.  Your expected result is missing `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = defaultdict(dict)
# ...
n[tenant_id] = g
```

indeed overwrites the key with the value of `tenant_id`. Instead of setting a value with `=`, call a method on the result, like this:

```
n = defaultdict(dict)
n[tenant_id].update(g)
```

Seeing that your expected result is not valid Python, you may want to have list values instead of dicts. Easy:

```
n = defaultdict(list)
# ...
n[tenant_id].append(g)
```

Comment: I tried "update" it seems not working.
As well as unable to use list, I need dict only. for ease of parsing.

Comment: @iamnewuser Yes, see the part after that. Also, can you elaborate how *it's not working*? First of all, make sure you understand what value you expect, and make sure that that is an actual Python value.